# run Groovy CLI from groovy jar placed in war

Tags: groovy, jar, clojure, command-line-interface

I know about Groovysh, but I need to know if it is possible to run groovy CLI directly from groovy.jar placed in deployed war servlet (using one command). I can simplify question. Is there possibility to run Groovy CLI like it works, for example, in Clojure?

```
java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure.main
```

And CLI appears in terminal. This is how things look in clojure. I am looking for one line command which will run groovy CLI in terminal (using only groovy library to run it). I was looking for help in javadoc, found classes which should help, but don't know how to run it. :f

http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/GroovyShell.html

(If someone knows solution which doesn't meet all criterias, also please answer.)

//EDIT

It seems that it needs groovy.jar, commons-cli.jar, antlr.jar,  asm-util.jar and jline.jar. So I've added those files in my war file in WEB-INF/lib directory. Maybe it's good solution to make my own jar which role will be to call Groovy CLI from other jars, but now the question is, how ro run jar placed in WEB-INF/lib directory inside deployed war application via command line?

Greets

Comment: sir your comment for the below answer seems to be correct.please post that as "answer to your question" and accept it. So in future people may see that answer.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like groovysh depends on more libs than the embeddable version contains. I managed to do what you want by using the following command:

```
$ java -classpath '*' org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main
```

But the current directory had to be the dir where all the groovy libs are; i.e. `$GROOVY_HOME/lib`:

```
$ cd $GROOVY_HOME/lib
$ java -classpath '*' org.codehaus.groovy.tools.shell.Main
Groovy Shell (2.0.6, JVM: 1.6.0_24)
Type 'help' or '\h' for help.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000>
```

Comment: It seems that it needs groovy.jar, commons-cli.jar, antlr.jar, asm-util.jar and jline.jar. So I've added those files in my war file in WEB-INF/lib directory. Maybe it's good solution to make my own jar which role will be to call Groovy CLI from other jars, but now the question is, how ro run jar placed in WEB-INF/lib directory inside deployed war application via command line?

Comment: can you run a command like `pwd` from the web application? my bet is that it will be in the root directory, thus you will need to point the `-classpath` to `/context-name/WEB-INF/lib` or something like that